# Reading values from Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, single-page-application

In the past when developing dynamically loading multi-control single page type applications I had huge amount of headaches with viewstate. The reason for this was that controls have to be added on **OnInit** stage, and not after. Since I was handling an control event (for example, selectedIndexChanged on dropdownlist) I was loading them in the event handler stage. I know about the child control page cycle catch-up, but I have noticed that sometimes it just does not work.

I once again have been tasked with developing such an application. This time I decided to take a different approach. For those selection controls which load a dynamic control based on their value, I will check their postback response values (from Request.Form) during the OnInit stage and load the control immediately. I will not load any dynamic controls from the event handler stage since this is right before OnPreRender and it too late.

In summary: 
What are the pitfalls of checking a control's values from the Request.Form collection early in the page cycle (for example OnInit) and then performing an action, instead of check that value from the actual control later in the page cycle?

Answer (score 0):

One of the pitfalls is that if the control isn't included in the `<form>` it won't exist. I would recommend going ahead and adding them in the event handler stage - because that's when you know what you want to add - but store the necessary information to reconstruct those controls in either `ViewState` or `SessionState`.

By doing this you'll be able to recreate them in `OnInit`, but not have to deal with some of the other complexities surrounding the road you're headed down now.

So, let's say you found you needed to build a control. You'd build it:

```
var tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "myTextBox";
...
```

but you'd also save the necessary state information:

```
this.ViewState.StoreControl(typeof(TextBox), "myTextBox");
```

and then just build the extension method:

```
public static void StoreControl(this StateBag vs, Type controlType, string name)
{
    var dynamicControls = vs["DynamicControls"] as List<Tuple<Type, string>>;
    if (dynamicControls == null)
    {
        dynamicControls = new List<Tuple<Type, string>>();
        vs["DynamicControls"] = dynamicControls;
    }

    var t = dynamicControls.FirstOrDefault(tp => tp.Item2 == name);
    if (t == null) { dynamicControls.Add(Tuple.Create(controlType, name)); }
}
```

then in `OnInit` you might do something like this:

```
var dynamicControls = vs["DynamicControls"] as List<Tuple<Type, string>>;
if (dynamicControls != null)
{
    foreach (var tp in dynamicControls)
    {
        Control c = Activator.CreateInstance(tp.Item1) as Control;
        c.ID = tp.Item2;
        this.Controls.Add(c);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this code was written on SO. It's not been compiled or debugged. But you get the idea.

Comment: How can an asp.net server control not be included in the <form>?

Comment: @BlueChameleon, it can be done, I've done it. I'm not saying it would be mainstream - I'm just saying it can be done. But also, please see my edit.

Comment: Honestly, I see what you are doing here, but your original pitfall that you mentioned will never happen in our system, because if we start adding controls outside of form we cannot use Control.FindControl() to find them and that would break everything. Plus a bunch of the standard ASP.NET controls call System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm() to make sure they are in a form, otherwise they start throwing errors.

Comment: @BlueChameleon, `FindControl` works on a naming container, not a `<form>` tag. If using the `Page` as the naming container, it would find all controls on the page. Now, if you add all of your controls to a `<form>` tag, that's cool.